# Syntax propertizing an exception to Python comment rule

Tags: syntax

I want to write a mode for the Cadabra 2 computer algebra system, which has Python-like syntax, with an exception of having the hash character `#` as a wild card in expressions, in addition to being a comment starter like in regular Python. Consider the following code:

```
\dalembert{ A?? }::LaTeXForm(\Box A??).

{ \mu, \nu }::Indices(vector).
\dalembert{#}::Derivative.
\partial{#}::PartialDerivative.
{ A_{\mu} }::Depends(\partial{#}).

# QED Lagrangian
lagrangian:= (a/2) A_{\mu} \dalembert{ A_{\mu} }
    + (b/2) A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}{\partial_{\mu}{ A_{\nu} }}
    + (1/2) m**2 A_{\mu} * A^{\mu};
```

Here, the `QED Lagrangian` line is a comment, but `}::Derivative.` is not. I want Emacs to interpret `#` as a comment delimiter only if it is not enclosed by curly or regular braces, and am struggling to implement that. The way I believe it should be done is with the syntax propertization function:

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode my-cadabra2-mode python-mode "cadabra2 mode"
  "Major mode for Cadabra 2 computer algebra system"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '((my-cadabra2-font-lock-keywords)))
  (setq-local syntax-propertize-function
              (syntax-propertize-rules ("\\(?<!{\s*\\)#\\(?!\s*}\\)" (1 "< ")))))
```

I believe my regular expression is correct, it should match `#` if not preceded by `{` and not followed by `}` with any whitespace in between. Emacs still uses any hash as a comment starter however.

How do I implement this properly?

Comment: Well, just trying to eval your function in my `*scratch*` buffer gives an `(invalid-regexp)` in your argument to `syntax-propetize-rules`.

Comment: Looks like you've got a negative-lookbehind and a negative-lookahead, both of which aren't supported. Also it looks like you're trying to use `\s` to match whitespace. You want `\s-` instead. See https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression for a good primer on emacs regexes.

Comment: @nega I'm trying to make this work with the simplest example, I tried `(rx (and "#" (not "}")))` which evaluates just fine and should catch the non-comments in the provided example, but still does not work when I load a file with the mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your recent comment it *is* working, except for the fact that you're not *overriding* the comment character, you're adding properties to it. Effectively your `(define-derived-mode ...)` is saying "add this additional property to the comment character" and not "set the comment character to this property".

Additionally, you want to use `0` in your rule. The integer there is the matching sub-group of the regex in the rule, with `0` being "the whole match".

With your (slightly modified) sample text

```
# -*- mode: my-cadabra2 -*-

# bol comment
\dalembert{ A?? }::LaTeXForm(\Box A??). # inline comment

{ \mu, \nu }::Indices(vector).
\dalembert{#}::Derivative.
\partial{#}::PartialDerivative.
{ A_{\mu} }::Depends(\partial{#}).

# QED Lagrangian
lagrangian:= (a/2) A_{\mu} \dalembert{ A_{\mu} }
    + (b/2) A_{\mu} \partial_{\nu}{\partial_{\mu}{ A_{\nu} }}
    + (1/2) m**2 A_{\mu} * A^{\mu};
```

And this version of your defined of your `define-derived-mode` (note the `modify-syntax-entry` line)

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(define-derived-mode my-cadabra2-mode python-mode "cadabra2 mode"
  "Major mode for Cadabra 2 computer algebra system"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(python-font-lock-keywords))
  (modify-syntax-entry ?# ".") ;; set # to be punctuation
  (set (make-local-variable 'syntax-propertize-function)
              (syntax-propertize-rules ((rx (and "#" (not "}"))) (0 "<")))))
```

I get:

[image: derived mode with working comment highlighting]

Comment: Is there a function to force drawing the propertized syntax? It takes a while for Emacs to start displaying normal comments properly after startup now